# I am trying to write a method that combines two arrays of strings into one new array of strings, but I am blocked with a casting error

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Here is my Code:

```
    static BagInterface<String> createCombineBag(BagInterface<String> aBag1, BagInterface<String> aBag2){
         if (aBag1 == null || aBag2 == null) {
             return null; // Return null if aBag1 or aBag2 is null
         }

         BagInterface<String> newBag = new LinkedBag<>(); // Create a new bag to store the combined data

         // Add all elements from aBag1 to the new bag
         for (String element : aBag1.toArray()) {
             newBag.add(element);
         }

         // Add all elements from aBag2 to the new bag
         for (String element : aBag2.toArray()) {
             newBag.add(element);
         }

         return newBag;
}
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.String; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.String; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Here is an example of what I am expecting:

> Example:   if aBag1 contains data:  "hello", "Hello", "world"
> aBag2 contains data:  "abc", "hello", "def"
> newBag contains: "hello", "Hello", "world", "abc", "hello", "def"

Comment: If Bag is an Iterable, you don't need to copy it to an array. Just iterate over the content of the bag by writing `for (var element : aBag1){...}`

Comment: `BagInterface aBag1, BagInterface aBag2` should be `BagInterface<String> aBag1, BagInterface<String> aBag2` (As is `aBag1` and `aBag2` could be holding anything, they are **raw types**). Similarly, you should make the return type a `BagInterface<String>` instead of leaving it as a raw `BagInterface`.

Comment: The error is due to `toArray` returning you an Object[], which is not necessarily a String. You could use `toArray(String[]::new)` but that also might fail, due to what Elliott wrote.

Comment: I would definitely take a look at your modules, because there is a reason that they are named in your Exception. Try to use your code in a non modular application.

Comment: Live Valerij is saying, you can iterate over the bags, no need to cast to array: for (String element : aBag1) {